Oil level drops very low then rises very high, what's the cause?
2012 Nissan X-Trail, 2.5l naturally aspirated petrol engine, 235,000km on the clock.
I thought I had a blown head gasket, but now I'm not sure.

Between regular services, I noticed the engine getting noisy, so I checked the oil and it was very low (below minimum mark on dipstick). There was no oil on the floor of my garage and I didn't see any other signs of a leak at the time. Topped up the oil, wife took it for service and they said the oil filter was quite loose so maybe it had leaked. Wasn't satisfied with that answer but we moved on.
Months later, same thing happens again. Topped up the oil, but only enough to get it over the minimum.
Maybe a month later, I check the oil and now it's way over the maximum. So I wonder if coolant is getting into it. Check coolant level and see it's below the minimum.

So I figure I have a blown head gasket and coolant has migrated through it into the oil. That was the only thing I could think of that would cause the oil level to rise. I haven't topped up the coolant because if it's reached an equilibrium I don't want to change that and have more coolant get into the oil.
I'm not ready to pay for a full repair so I got some head gasket sealer, but before using it I wanted to double check that the gasket is compromised. I took the radiator cap off and looked into it while the engine was running, but didn't see bubbles and the coolant colour seems okay.
Also:

it's not blowing a lot of smoke
the check engine light isn't on
it's not overheating
on closer inspection there is oil on an engine mount below the engine, so maybe it was leaking at some point or still is (but nothing is reaching my garage floor) (see photo)
there is a pretty noticeable wacka-wacka-wacka noise from the engine when accelerating, which concerns me, but maybe it's unrelated
I always check the oil on a flat surface when the engine hasn't been running for a while.

Question: despite the lack of evidence, could it still be a compromised head gasket? Just compromised in a way that doesn't introduce air/oil into the coolant?
Otherwise, what could cause the oil level to rise like that?


